# C++ app behaving differently when executed from a python script

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, file

I have a C++ app and executing this app from terminal gives the perfect result. It takes a string(a text file) and another string(query) as arguments. But when I execute the same app passing same parameters from a python script it just does not read the whole text file and thus gives incorrect output. I have used ifstream to read from the given argument files and processed data to insert in a trie (I don't think details of the app matter here). I can see not all the words of the text file are being inserted in case of the app being executed from Python script.

```
subprocess.call([path_to_app , file parameter , query])
os.system(path_to_app + file paremeter + query)
```

I have tried both of the above commands and both give the same result(incorrect).

---

Showing outputs in each case when executed from terminal and from python script

**Case 1 :**

```
Argument file received is /home/atul/DocumentSearchEngine/a1.txt
Arguemnt Query Received is data
6
here are the words Matching with query as prefix 
data database databases 
Total Score 6
Totalwords Inserted in the Trie are : 271
```

**Case 2 :**

```
Argument file received is /home/atul/DocumentSearchEngine/a1.txt
Arguemnt Query Received is data
0
here are the words Matching with query as prefix 

Total Score 0
Totalwords Inserted in the Trie are : 0
```

---

C++ Code of app

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


struct Trie{
    int words;
    int prefixes;
    Trie* a[128];
};

void initialise(Trie *vertex){
    vertex->words = 0;
    vertex->prefixes =0;
    for(int i=0;i<128;i++){
        vertex->a[i] = NULL;
    }
}

int totalwords = 0;

void addWord(Trie *vertex , string word , int index){
    if(index == word.size()){
        vertex->words = vertex->words+1;
        vertex->prefixes = vertex->prefixes + 1;
        totalwords ++ ;
    }
    else{
        vertex->prefixes = vertex->prefixes + 1;
        int k = word[index];
        if(!vertex->a[k]){
            vertex->a[k] = new Trie();
            initialise(vertex->a[k]);
        }
        addWord(vertex->a[k],word,index+1);

    }
}

int countWords(Trie *vertex , string word, int index){
    int k = word[index];
    if(index == word.length()){
        return vertex->words;
    }
    else if(!vertex->a[k]){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return countWords(vertex->a[k],word,index+1);
    }
}

int countPrefixes(Trie *vertex , string prefix , int index){
    int k = prefix[index];
    if(index == prefix.length()){
        return vertex->prefixes;
    }
    else if(!vertex->a[k]){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return countPrefixes(vertex->a[k],prefix,index+1);
    }

}

void getWords(vector<string> &ans, Trie *vertex , string prefix){
    if(!vertex)
        return ;
    for(int i=0 ; i < 128 ;i++){
        if(vertex->a[i]){
            char x = (char)i;
            string dummy = prefix + x;
            if(vertex->a[i]->words){
                ans.push_back(dummy);
            }
            getWords(ans,vertex->a[i] , dummy);
        }
    }
}


void AllWords(Trie *vertex,  string prefix , int index ,vector<string> &ans){
    if(index == prefix.length()){
        if(vertex){
            if(vertex->words)
                ans.push_back(prefix);
            getWords(ans,vertex,prefix);
        }
    }
    else{
        int k = prefix[index];
        if(!vertex->a[k])
            return ;
        return AllWords(vertex->a[k] , prefix, index+1 , ans);
    }
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[]){

    string filename = argv[1];
    ifstream infile(filename);
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("/home/atul/DocumentSearchEngine/result.txt" , ios_base::app);


    Trie *root = new Trie();
    initialise(root);
    string word;
    while(infile>>word){
        addWord(root,word,0);
    }

    string query=  argv[2];

    stringstream ss(query);

    cout<<"Argument file received is "<<filename<<endl;
    cout<<"Arguemnt Query Received is "<<query<<endl;

    double score =  0 ;
    int total_words = 0;
    while(getline(ss,word,' ')){
        total_words++;
        int x = countPrefixes(root,word,0);
        vector<string>ans ;
        cout<<x<<endl;
        score += x;
        cout<<"here are the words Matching with query as prefix \n";
        AllWords(root, word , 0 ,ans);
        for(auto x : ans){
            cout<<x<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;

    }
    score /= total_words;
    cout<<"Total Score "<<score<<endl;
    cout<<"Totalwords Inserted in the Trie are : "<<totalwords<<endl;
    outfile<<score<<endl;
}
```

---

Python Script

```
infiles = ["a.txt" , "b.txt" , "c.txt" , "d.txt" ,"e.txt" , "f.txt" , "g.txt" , "h.txt" , "i.txt" , "j.txt" ]
outfiles = ["a1.txt" , "b1.txt" , "c1.txt" , "d1.txt" ,"e1.txt" , "f1.txt" , "g1.txt" , "h1.txt" , "i1.txt" , "j1.txt" ]

def Result(query):
    total_tries = 0
    for file in os.listdir("/home/atul/DocumentSearchEngine"):
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
            print file
            command = "pdf2txt.py -o "+ infiles[total_tries] + " " + file
            print command
            os.system(command)
            f = open(infiles[total_tries] , "r")
            data = f.read().replace('\n',' ')
            data = dataProcssing(data)
            words = data.split()
            a = []
            for word in words:
                # print word
                if len(word)>=4:
                    a.append(word)
            output_file = open("/home/atul/DocumentSearchEngine/"+outfiles[total_tries],'w')
            for x in a:
                output_file.write(x)
                output_file.write(' ')
            curr = "/home/atul/DocumentSearchEngine/"+outfiles[total_tries]
            # print "sending file " + curr + "\n"
            # subprocess.call(['/home/atul/CODES/murguddin' , curr , query])
            command = "/home/atul/DocumentSearchEngine/./a.out "+curr+" "+query
            os.system(command)
            # print x
            # x = float(x)
            total_tries =  total_tries + 1
            # dic = {file : x}
            # score.update(dic)
    return total_tries
```

---

Sample input file which is generated by processing pdf to text

```
documentation splitsense introduction project solve problem splitting expenses among group friends feature simplifying debt which when used gives minimum number transactions among friends settle bills developed implemented greedy algorithm implement this feature used serve webpages dynamic data used mysql store transactions users while modelling every transaction directed graph what going first many users entered database every transactions among users there ways when single user pays when more than user pays form takes data from logged user about pays what uses what this data then processed stored text file edges with columns payer payee amount these edges stored databases need superior computation solve with multiple edges users where comes picture have used binary executable which computes required values transactions minimum transactions according algorithm mentioned below this writes output text file which later read file output shown user friendly html webpage thus this wrapped parts logic part other presentation part wrapped algorithm used simplifying debt feature uses greedy algorithm which goes like this maintain total worth each node amount given amount received received amount treated negative given amount treated positive involved transaction maintain priority queues nodes with total worth negative other total worth positive select element both priority queues check which smaller magnitude remove from their corresponding queues this removal represent transactions keep doing this till priority queues empty thus greedily select highest that what gives least number transactions clear debts conclusion this project just attempt solve simple problem splitting bills this project grown features where instead users database group users only involved transaction multiple challenges ahead terms scaling this security overall this good learning experience good exposure both internet technologies application algorithms
```

What could possibly be wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you debug your program? This is the only right way for you to solve a problem.

Comment: @k.v. I tried to debug my program. There is no issue in the logic.  I can guess the only issue could be the way these calls work as I don't understand after executing the same command how can only a part of the file is being read?

Comment: 1.  Print out each of the arguments to make sure that your program is receiving the arguments you expect.  (Surround the output with double quote or some other visible character so that you can see if there is any unexpected white space).  2.  Check that opening `infile` works.  3.  Print your current directory.

Comment: You should seek for an issue not in logic, but in "infrastructure". Make sure that in both cases your program receives *the same* values of cmd args, then - that it reads *from same file* (maybe issue with paths), then - that it reads *the same data* from files... This way you will find the exact place, where difference occurs

Comment: 4. If none of the above help, simplify your program to the absolute minimum (perhaps print out the query and just copy the input file).  Simplify your python script to the minimum (just call your program), and edit your question to include the program and the python script.

Comment: At the moment, I am voting to close because this does not contain a [mcve].

Comment: Are you using a full path to the input file? otherwise it might not be running with the same input depending on the directory it's working in.

Comment: @PeteKirkham, I am adding complete path to the input file.

Comment: @MartinBonner what other information can I provide, please?

Comment: You need to minimize the C++ program while still displaying the problem.  (I think just count the words in the input and display the query would be enough).  You need to include a minimal (complete) python script which displays the problem.  You need to show a minimal input file which displays the problem.  You will need to update the outputs in the two cases.

Comment: @MartinBonner, I have updated the question with your suggestions, but I can't reduce the C++ code as this is the core of the project, please bear with that

Comment: You misunderstand.  We don't care about your project.  No new reader of this question will care about your project.  You need a *separate* program which has the same problem as your project, but is simpler than your project.  That is the program that *must* be in your question.  Once you have got that working, you can apply the same solution to your project.

Comment: That's not a minimal python script.

Comment: You are still not checking whether you managed to open `infile` (my guess is "no").

Comment: @MartinBonner I wrote a minimal script and that worked so how do I incorporate what changed, I can't figure out the mistake in the script

Comment: ... and I think your problem is that you haven't closed the file in python before calling the C++ program.  Use the `with` statement to close the python file.

Comment: Minimal script works:  That is a huge step forward.  Now you need to work from the full script towards the minimal, or the minimal towards the full, and find the change that makes it work.

Comment: @MartinBonner earlier tried  `with` but same thing happens, so used this and no changes

Comment: @MartinBonner , what I was doing earlier was I process the text and sent that as argument to the app in the same pass but now I process the text store it as text as send again to app in next pass (current version works but not the first one)

Comment: @hulk_baba just take a debugger and go with a program step by step: first - when it works ok (run from cmd), second - when it works incorrect (from python). Or print all variables values and observe them for the first and second case. And this way you will find a place, where difference occurs. Otherwise all of this is just a try to guess.